# d3.js - Having a tree layout, how to change the X-axis to use a time scale in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this tree layout and need it to use a time scale in the X-axis to fix the nodes to dates. Also, I would need to keep the root node (it has a `is_root` property in the JSON data) outside of the time scale.
[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kIJxo) is the Codepen with the tree layout working and I also paste the code here:

```
var json = {
  "name": "Meet Treat",
  "is_root": true,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Meeting 1",
      "date": "Sun Jan 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Meeting 2",
          "date": "Tue Jan 10 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Meeting 5",
              "date": "Fri Feb 10 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Meeting 4",
          "date": "Wed Feb 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Meeting 3",
      "date": "Fri Jan 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Meeting 7",
          "date": "Thu Mar 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Meeting 8",
              "date": "Sat Mar 10 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Meeting 6",
      "date": "Mon Feb 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Meeting 9",
          "date": "Tue Mar 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)"
        },
        {
          "name": "Meeting 10",
          "date": "Sun Apr 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Meeting 13",
              "date": "Tue May 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Meeting 11",
      "date": "Tue Apr 10 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Meeting 14",
          "date": "Thu May 10 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)"
        },
        {
          "name": "Meeting 16",
          "date": "Fri Jun 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Meeting 12",
      "date": "Fri Apr 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Meeting 15",
          "date": "Sun May 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Meeting 17",
              "date": "Sun Jun 10 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Meeting 18",
          "date": "Wed Jun 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Meeting 19",
      "date": "Sun Jul 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Meeting 21",
          "date": "Fri Jul 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Meeting 22",
              "date": "Wed Aug 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "Meeting 23",
                  "date": "Fri Aug 10 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Meeting 24",
                  "date": "Mon Aug 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "Meeting 25",
                      "date": "Sat Sep 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Meeting 27",
          "date": "Thu Sep 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Meeting 20",
      "date": "Tue Jul 10 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Meeting 26",
          "date": "Mon Sep 10 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Meeting 28",
              "date": "Mon Oct 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Meeting 29",
          "date": "Wed Oct 10 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};


var m = [20, 120, 20, 120],
    w = 1280 - m[1] - m[3],
    h = 1000 - m[0] - m[2],
    i = 0,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([h, w]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var vis = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
    .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

root = json;
root.x0 = h / 2;
root.y0 = 0;
update(root);

function update(source) {
  var duration = d3.event && d3.event.altKey ? 5000 : 500;

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      ;//.on("click", function(d) { toggle(d); update(d); });
  nodeEnter.append('image')
    .attr('xlink:href', 'http://www.uni-regensburg.de/Fakultaeten/phil_Fak_II/Psychologie/Psy_II/beautycheck/english/durchschnittsgesichter/m(01-32)_gr.jpg')
    .attr('width', 40)
    .attr('height', 40)
    .attr('x', -40)
    .attr('y', -20)
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip1)');
  var clip1 = nodeEnter.append('clipPath')
    .attr('id', 'clip1')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0);
  clip1.append('circle')
    .attr('r', 20)
    .attr('cx', -20);
  nodeEnter.append('image')
    .attr('xlink:href', 'http://0.tqn.com/d/hairremoval/1/0/e/-/-/-/eyebrow-classic.jpg')
    .attr('width', 40)
    .attr('height', 40)
    .attr('x', 0 )
    .attr('y', -20)
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip2)');
  var clip2 = nodeEnter.append('clipPath')
    .attr('id', 'clip2')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0);
  clip2.append('circle')
    .attr('r', 20)
    .attr('cx', 20);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  // Update the links…
  var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
    .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}
```

The code is messy because I'm playing with a example.
What I've tried is adding a time scale like this:

```
var timeScale = d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date(2012, 10, 1)]).range([100, w]);
```

and replacing this line (#231):

```
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });
```

with this:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + timeScale(new Date(d.date)) + "," + d.x + ")"; });
```

or this:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + timeScale(new Date(d.date)) + ")"; });
```

But no luck, they loose coherent position. Also, I don't know why in the example I'm basing on, it applies the CSS transition `translate` using Y and then X values, where the CSS specification for `translate` states that values should be X first, then Y. Is there something that I'm missing from `tree.nodes()`?

Answer (score 4):

I figured out how to do it. First, we need to create a time scale:

```
var timeScale = d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date(2012, 10, 1)]).range([100, w]);
```

Notice that I've put a fixed date range. You can build a logic to use your data to get that.

Then, update the transition for the nodes...

```
var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var y = timeScale(new Date(d.date));
    if (d3.map(d).has('is_root')) {
      y = d.y;
    }
    return "translate(" + y + "," + d.x + ")";
  });
```

...and the transition for the links:

```
link.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("d", function (d) {
    if (d3.map(d.source).has('is_root') && d.source.is_root) {
      return diagonal({ source: { x: d.source.x, y: d.source.y }, target: { x: d.target.x, y: timeScale(new Date(d.target.date)) } });
    }
    return diagonal({ source: { x: d.source.x, y: timeScale(new Date(d.source.date)) }, target: { x: d.target.x, y: timeScale(new Date(d.target.date)) } });
  });
```

Finally, if you want to show the date ticks on the graph, you can add the following code, otherwise, not needed.

```
var dates = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= 20; j += 9) {
    (j == 19) && (j = 20);
    dates.push(new Date(2012, i, j));
  }
}

var axisGroup = vis.append('svg:g');
axisGroup.selectAll('.xTicks')
  .data(dates)
  .enter()
  .append('svg:line')
  .attr('x1', timeScale)
  .attr('y1', -5)
  .attr('x2', timeScale)
  .attr('y2', h + 5)
  .attr('stroke', 'lightgray')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1)
  .attr('class', 'xTicks');
axisGroup.selectAll('text.xAxisBottom')
  .data(dates)
  .enter()
  .append('svg:text')
  .text(function (datum) { return datum.getDate() + '/' + (datum.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + datum.getFullYear(); })
  .attr('x', timeScale)
  .attr('y', h + 20)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('class', 'xAxisBottom');
```

It generates the dates that will be ticked and add the corresponding lines and labels.

As for...

> Also, I don't know why in the example I'm basing on, it applies the CSS transition translate using Y and then X values, where the CSS specification for translate states that values should be X first, then Y. Is there something that I'm missing from tree.nodes()?

Creating the diagonal for the links this way:

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal().projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
```

inverts the X & Y axis using the projection method and giving it a function that returns the axis inverted. That's why Y becomes X and vice versa.

Comment: I tried to use your code to create a time scale in the X-axis & fix the nodes to dates but i wasn't able to get it working. Could you be so kind and provide a working example?

Comment: @TheDoctor this answer is 6 years old now. There's a good chance that D3.js changed the API completely. I think I've been using version 2.5.2. The current version is 5.5.0. I encourage you to look for a more up to date example or if you still want to try my solution, use version 2.5.2, which is 6 years old. I don't use D3.js at the moment so I cannot provide a more up to date example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Date` instances, get the milliseconds from them with `getTime()` and use these numbers to scale the axis.

Using milliseconds, you can easily map back and forth between `Date` instances and the axis (`new Date(millis)` <-> `d.getTime()`)

Comment: Can you explain a little further? Are you suggesting that I use milliseconds as X pixel values?

Comment: Well, you will need to scale them before you can use the milliseconds as X pixel values. d3 should do the same when you use `d3.time.scale()` but maybe there is a bug. On second thought, maybe there is a bug in your code. What happens when you remove the odd `(ART)` from the date strings? And what do you mean by "loose coherent position"?